# Dúvida ao contar elementos de uma tabela no formato chr

Tags: r

Como consigo contar os aeroportos de chegada se estão descritos na tabela em formato ?

Já usei este código e não obtive o resultado esperado:

```
destino_frequente <- flights %>% 
        select(origin, dest) %>%
        arrange(desc(origin))
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você possa resolver utilizando o count do dplyr:

```
flights %>% count(dest))
```